# constantly get the log output from a website

Tags: javascript, html

There is a website https://skybeje.net/gijilock/ which records voices and returns the transcripts when clicking the out CSV. 
"I did not make this website, so I can not change the .js file or use the functions on cosole."
What I need is to get the txt file of database every two seconds automatically. 
I believe that this function is related to exporting the txt file of DB. but I am new to javascrip, so I don't know how to use it.

```
    ExportTimeline() {
        this._timelineDB.ReadAllData(e=>{
            this._homeDB.ReadAllData(t=>{
                let n = this.ToPlainText(e.Messages, t.Rooms)
                  , o = l.default.GetDefaultFileName("gijilock", "txt");
                l.default.Export(o, n)
            }
            )
        }
        )
    }
```

I would be glad if some body helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it every two seconds as shown below:

```js
setTimeout(ExportTimeline, 2000);
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is that I am not the website admin and this code on console would result in VM185:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ExportTimeline is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:12